Problem about upper limit and lower limit
This problem is from Garling's book (A Course in Mathematical Analysis, Volume 1, Exercise 3.5.2). $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n}$ and $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n}$ are lower limit and upper limit of a sequence $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{^\infty}$, respectively.
Problem Suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{^\infty}$ is a bounded sequence. Let $s_{n} = a_{0} + \cdots + a_{n}$. Show that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_{n} \le 
  \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_{n}}{n+1} \le
  \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_{n}}{n+1} \le
  \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_{n}. $$
I've figured out that the sequence $\left(\frac{s_{n}}{n+1}\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is bounded, but after that, I can't think of a way to approach it. Even the smallest hint would be very helpful.

Hint for last inequality: There exists $k$ such that $a_i \le \lim \sup_i a_i+\epsilon$  for all $i \ge k$. $\lim \sup_n \frac {s_n}{n+1}=\lim \sup_n \frac {a_k+a_{k+1}+...+a_n} {n+1} \le \lim \sup_n \frac {(n-k+1)\lim \sup_i a_i} {n+1}=\lim \sup_i a_i$.
The left-hand inequality is similar.
